# Удаление окончания у слов в списке

Tags: c#

Есть список содержащий различные символы:

```
84ыва846ыв88сСлово545выщв
324ошаовыщоСловоаошуа
лщвфыозСловофаовшщв
```

Необходимо убрать из строки все символы, включая `Слово` и все символы, что следуют за ним.
Количество символов до и после конкретного слова могут быть различны.

Читал различные ресурсы, но только редактирование находил по определенному символу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создадим метод `RemoveWords(str, word)`.

В теле метода получаем индекс методом `IndexOf(str, word)` и `Remove(startIndex, length)` удаляем все символы.

Почитать про `StringBuilder` можно вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0)

Почитать про `IndexOf()` можно вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0)

Почитать про `Remove()` можно вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-6.0)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "84ыва846ыв88сСлово545выщв";

    string removedWordString = RemoveWord(str, "Слово");
    Console.WriteLine(removedWordString);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string RemoveWords(string str, string word)
{
    if(!str.Contains(word))
      throw new ArgumentException("not found");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
    int index = str.IndexOf(word);
    builder.Remove(index, str.Length - index);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Необходимо обрезать Слово и **все что после него**.

Comment: @tym32167 исправил

Comment: Зачем так сложно? `string word = "Hello"; string result = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(word) + word.Length);`

Comment: И никого не смущает тот факт, что если ничего не будет найдено, то будет что-то неладное? =)

Comment: @aepot да, билдер тут явно не нужен т.к работа со строкой тут маленькая, но менять не буду раз уж ответ приняли

Answer (score 1):

Решение в одну строку:

```
string CutTextByWord(string text, string word) => text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(word));
```

---

Вот как это выглядит:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "84ыва846ыв88сСлово545выщв";
            var word = "Слово";

            Console.WriteLine(CutTextByWord(text, word));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string CutTextByWord(string text, string word) => text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(word));
    }
}
```

---

Результат: 84ыва846ыв88с